# How to increase max threads in ASP .NET Core 3.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, threadpool

I have an ASP .NET Core 3.0 web api application deployed in a docker container. It looks like the the max threads available to handle requests is around 240 (as it appears to max out on some nodes for periods of time, correlated with a garbage collection event). It does not look like this is a memory issue as only about 1/5 of the configured memory is in use. Is there a way to increase the max number of threads? Can I just set ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads() in Startup.cs?

Comment: Instead of increasing Thread count, try to profile your application and see which thread is locked, if you use `async await` correctly, you will not have to worry about threads being locked. Threads are mostly locked due to synchronous API.

Comment: threads are manage by OS or the server. In IIS you can set maximum worker process count in related application pool.

Comment: Its a docker image running Kestrel.

Answer (score 1):

I called ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() in Startup.cs. There is also a SetMaxThreads(), but this did not increase the number of threads. Link to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads

Comment: Yeah, interesting. The page says ‘Applies to .Net Core 3.1’ as well as others (down near the bottom). The information on this page worked in my .Net Core app. Removed the view parameter from the link.